# Regex to prevent the entering of white space?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I want validate that a username doesn't contain spaces. I want use `AZ-az-09` and `_` character in my string and ingore another. I have a regex but it is no  validating spaces.

```
[RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9  .&'-]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Boşluk ve özel karakter girmeyiniz.")]
```

How can do it?

Comment: A validator doesn't ignore anything. It validates that a value matches a regular expression. What do you mean by ignore white space? Do you want to validate that a username doesn't contains white space?

Comment: ı want username dosent contains space

Comment: as you want to prevent enterring whitespace you want to post it to server to do this or in browser? , if in browser/client side then you should put javascript as a tag... shouldn't you ?

Comment: You should use a pattern in HTML to *prevent* whitespace from being entered. Then you should check the pattern once the form is submitted to ensure no whitespace was added (as anything you send the client can be changed, including your restrictions on whitespace)